# ActiveMQ warning: Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB

Tags: jms, activemq-classic

I'm trying to switch from a legacy jms broker to ActiveMQ.

One thing I cannot figure out is a warning in the logs *once per hour*:

```
WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:38542 failed: java.io.IOException: 
  Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB | ...
```

It's obviously some scheduled job in ActiveMQ that outputs this warning,
because it comes at the same minute every hour,
regardless of whether any messages are sent or not.

**But what exactly means "Frame size" here?**

We are ***not*** sending any jms-messages larger than a few kilobytes or so...

I read you can increase this "maxFramesize" in the connector, but doesn't help either.

When I try set it to 1GB (1073741824) (***or higher***) :

```
<transportConnector name="openwire" 
  uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=100&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=1073741824"/>
```

I still see the (now absurd) warning-message:

```
WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:42256 failed: java.io.IOException: 
  Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 1 GB
```

**What is ActiveMQ actually complaining about?**

**And how can I fix it?**

Comment: What version of ActiveMQ are you using? What protocol is your client using? Do you have the full stack-trace?

Comment: Also, if you want support for arbitrarily large messages you might consider ActiveMQ's next generation broker [Artemis](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/). It has [large message](http://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/large-messages.html) support.

Comment: Hi Justin. 
There is no stacktrace in the log, only the one-line Warning msg. Maybe there is some setting to get more debug info?

Comment: As I mentioned, the msgs we send are maximum a few KBs in size, so no need for larger msgs.  And the warning comes once/hour, regardless of whether we send any msgs or not, so it's obviously unrelated to the tiny msgs we send.

Comment: The connector/protocol is "openwire" (see config-line in OP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ActiveMQ 5 would only log this message if someone was sending your broker a message that is encoded to a size larger than the configured limit.  Since it happens to you on a regular interval then I'd look for some external resource that is doing something silly like trying to telnet into the broker Openwire port to check liveness and sending some garbage string or some such.  The broker would not be logging that error unless something was inbound so you need to start looking for the source of the errant sender.

Comment: It could be something like a security scanner. IIRC nCircle IP360 did something similar to see if our Tomcat servers were vulnerable or not.

Comment: Indeed, sounds like a periodic probe of some sort regularly hitting the broker port.

Comment: hmm... interesting input.  I'll see if I can setup a tcpdump to catch what's going on....

Comment: I found the reason, you were of course right :) --- there was a monitor-process for the old/legacy broker that we are now replacing, still "pinging" on same port, but speaking an entirely different protocol, thus some corrupt input that resulted in this warning. Thanks guys! :)