# Adding springboot security dependency causing activemq crash

Tags: spring-security

I am new to development and adding security to a spring boot application.
My application uses activeMQ and working fine.
But when I am adding the security dependency in POM file, the activemq stops working.'

Here is the dependency I am adding -

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
```

And this is started coming in the activeMQ logs -

WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52058 failed: java.io.IOException: Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB
WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52067 failed: java.io.IOException: Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB
WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52072 failed: java.io.IOException: Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB
WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52430 failed: java.io.IOException: Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB
WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:52435 failed: java.io.IOException: Frame size of 1 GB larger than max allowed 100 MB

This is getting printed in application logs-

2022-11-17 13:42:00.400 [ERROR] [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] - AMQ214013: Failed to decode packet
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: AMQ219032: Invalid type: 1
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.PacketDecoder.decode(PacketDecoder.java:499) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:67) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.ClientPacketDecoder.decode(ClientPacketDecoder.java:42) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.RemotingConnectionImpl.bufferReceived(RemotingConnectionImpl.java:388) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl$DelegatingBufferHandler.bufferReceived(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1263) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.ActiveMQChannelHandler.channelRead(ActiveMQChannelHandler.java:73) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:296) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:166) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:719) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:655) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:581) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
at org.apache.activemq.artemis.utils.ActiveMQThreadFactory$1.run(ActiveMQThreadFactory.java:118) ~[ctaas-bal-22.08.00-SNAPSHOT.jar:?]
2022-11-17 13:42:00.400 [ERROR] [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client] - AMQ214031: Failed to decode buffer, disconnect immediately.

```
 

I am trying to add a login page when someone trying to use API to get some information.
The login page will allow the information to retrieve if credentails are valid.
using the following example-

https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/
```

Comment: those both, security and queue are not relative as we can see in the error message. maybe you missed or added some configuration to activemq. check for those.

Comment: It could be related as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66682204/activemq-warning-frame-size-of-1-gb-larger-than-max-allowed-100-mb
Something could be sending a message to broker encoded in size larger than allowed limit.

Comment: I figured the root cause. One of the jar file provided by a different team has some 3rd party jars bundled causing activeMQ to crash. When I removed that and rebundled, it started working.